# Hide Activity until loading adview complete

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to hide activity until adview loading complete
I tried to put

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

in xml layout activiti but the activity keep showing without any effect of the abvor code

**Edit:**
it not somthing special it just starting activity from service

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, activiti.class);
        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Comment: If you added android:visibility="invisible" at root level it xml, it is for sure going to be invisible. It's visible means either layout you are using is different from what you intended to use or you changed visibility programatically. Plz share full layout file.

Comment: add your source code

Comment: You have to provide more code if you want to get proper answer. One can not help without proper information.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want to do so, you'll need to do it programmatically and set `visibility` to `gone` when your adview finished or etc. Now, it should hide the view all the time, anyways, you can try `gone` instead of `invisible` too.